# Pointing a domain name to a static IP of my PC

Tags: domain-name-system, iis, godaddy, a-record

I have a domain name with godaddy. Its present nameservers are **ns29.domaincontrol.com and ns30.domaincontrol.com**. I want to point this domain to a IP address of my PC. I have hosted some sites on IIS on my PC. I read several articles and find that editing the **@** record to the static IP would be sufficient. But I am little confused here.

1. Do I need to keep the name servers as above or do I need to change it. If yes, What would be my new name servers(Do I need to set it in IIS).
2. If I point the **@** record to the static IP of my PC, as I have multiple sites hosted on the IIS, How would my domain point to the correct site.
3. Do I also need to update the CName Record. I don't have any idea about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You need name servers; it's usually a hosted service, but you can install a DNS server on your machine if you know what you're doing. IIS doesn't have anything to do with DNS. When you buy a domain name, you are only buying the rights to use the name, nothing else. Associated with that name are glue records, pointing to name servers (the name servers are separate, they are not part of the purchase of a domain name).
2. The default record ("@" is used in some implementations as a placeholder) only returns results if someone enters the exact domain name; if they enter "www.example.com" then it doesn't match. Again, DNS has nothing to do with IIS. However the browser will send a HTTP Header called "Host" which specifies which website the browser was trying to connect to. IIS can use this header to figure out which website it should serve.
3. CName Records are something completely different from the Host Records (A Record, the default record is of this type). Not having any idea isn't a question.

Comment: as per your answer, IIS would resolve the correct site using HTTP Header sent by browser. How would I know what header my browser is sending and can I configure it.

Comment: Are you saying that you want to be able to type in "example.com" and be redirected to "example.com/LIMS/Login.aspx"? The Host Header sent by the browser is always the domain portion of the URL; this can not normally be changed.

Comment: yes, currently its opening the IIS7 page. And do I need to have some kind of mapping of Host Header and site in IIS.

Comment: Install [URL Rewrite](http://www.iis.net/download/urlrewrite), configure it to redirect from "/" to "/LIMS/Login.aspx". [Articles walking you through URL Rewrite can be found on Microsoft's Site](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/460/using-the-url-rewrite-module/). IIS needs to be configured to use Host Headers if it serves multiple sites on the same IP.

Comment: Thanks for providing the link. Can I avoid /LIMS/ between the domain name and page.aspx

Comment: Yes, the URL Rewrite software can also do that; add a rewrite rule instead of a redirect rule.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1758/discussion-between-vaibhav-and-chris-s)